# What different formats does RDFlib accept when reading lines into a graph in python?

Tags: python, xml, rdf

Can RDFlib take in lines of xml code to be put into a graph in python? I Know triples are generally what is used with RDFlib, but if I didn't have to convert them from XML to Turtle it would save a lot of work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that when you say “xml code” you actually mean RDF/XML, and that you have the entire RDF/XML document, not just a snippet of it, then yes, RDFlib accepts it. The documentation page [Loading and saving RDF](https://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro_to_parsing.html) starts with an example in N-Triples, but mentions how other formats are specified:

> #### Reading an NT file
>
> RDF data has various syntaxes (`xml`, `n3`, `ntriples`, `trix`, etc) that you might want to read. The simplest format is `ntriples`, a line-based format. Create the file demo.nt in the current directory with these two lines:
>
> ```
> <http://bigasterisk.com/foaf.rdf#drewp> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person> .
> <http://bigasterisk.com/foaf.rdf#drewp> <http://example.com/says> "Hello world" .
> ```
>
> You need to tell RDFLib what format to parse, use the `format` keyword-parameter to **`parse()`**, you can pass either a mime-type or the name (a [*list of available parsers*](https://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugin_parsers.html) is available). If you are not sure what format your file will be, you can use [**`rdflib.util.guess_format()`**](https://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apidocs/rdflib.html#rdflib.util.guess_format) which will guess based on the file extension.

In your case, you just need to use the `xml` (which actually means RDF/XML) format:

```
>>> g.parse("demo.rdf", format="xml")
```

Comment: Thanks @Joshua Taylor! I have been stuck on this for a while now!