# How to parse N3 in RDFlib

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib, n3

I am trying to convert a file into XML using the N3 parser in RDFlib but I am not sure if I am doing it right or even if I have the n3 plugin installed. This is what I have so far:

```python
import rdflib
from rdflib import URIRef, Graph, Namespace
from rdflib.plugins.parsers.notation3 import N3Parser

g = Graph()
result = g.parse(file=open("lemon_example_fear.txt", "r"), format="application/n3")
print (g.serialize(format='xml'))
```

This is not working but if I was to reverse the order with a working XML file it works fine

This is the error I get:

```
rdflib.plugin.PluginException: No plugin registered for (application/n3, <class 'rdflib.parser.Parser'>)
```

If anyone has a link to where to download the n3 plugin or just fix what I am doing wrong it would be great!

I am currently Running RDFlib 4.0.1 so it should be included shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17471664/1281433) to another one of your questions (in particular, check the [*list of available parsers*](https://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugin_parsers.html) link), the format argument would be `n3`, not `application/n3`.  If you do need to use the MIME type for the argument, the [N3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TeamSubmission/n3/#mimetype) says that the MIME type should be `text/n3`, not `application/n3`.

Comment: could you take a look on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493215/parse-rdf-file-python)?

Answer (score 1):

Just change format='application/n3' to format='n3'. It works!